# Environments / DAWs for writing scripts to process audio files

Tags: daw, batch-processing, script

I was looking for advice on any program where you could write scripts (as in code, eg Javascript etc) and use them to process audio files, using the usual range of audio effects, cutting/pasting etc.

Currently I do a bit using Adobe Audition, where you can record actions and apply them to other files, I guess im looking for something similar to the way you can use Javascript in Photoshop to create and edit documents.

This would be for creative use, my (perhaps over ambitious) desired end result would be being able to run a script on an audio file that would fashion it into an abstract composition.

Any leads would be appreciated, I work on a PC by the way.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Give Matlab a go, there's quite a few resources out there to get you started but if you have programmed at all before you should be able to pick it up fairly easily, I've seen it used mainly in acoustics applications but I'm sure you could find another possibly more creative use.

Comment: thanks, this looks like something worth pursuing, ive seen cakewalk used for experimental video stuff and hadnt really thought of it for music.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe http://puredata.info/? Might be easier than javascript for doing complex stuff.

Comment: yes i think this is somehting i want to look into more, i know you can make javascript objects for puredata also so that stretches the boundaries a bit of whats possible

Comment: Cool - didn't know about the javascript connection.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question... I've not played around with it very much, but the [Composers Desktop Project](http://www.composersdesktop.com/about.html) seems to be quite close to what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Such effects can be accomplished in javascript with the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) although the learning curve is steep.

Comment: Looks very cool!

Answer (score 2):

www.cakewalk.com

"Cakewalk Application Language (CAL) is an event-processing language based on C and LISP that you can use to extend Cakewalk products with custom editing commands. You can write your own CAL scripts, or use and edit CAL scripts that other people have written. You also can create CAL scripts by recording a series of commands, keystrokes, and mouse actions from within Cakewalk. This page contains a huge collection of CAL files and links to other CAL resources available on the Internet.

To use CAL you will need Cakewalk Pro for DOS, Cakewalk Professional for Windows, or Cakewalk Pro Audio. CAL dates back to Cakewalk for DOS and has evolved through the years. Because of this, all CAL files are not compatible with all versions of Cakewalk. Unfortunately, I do not have enough time to verify which Cakewalk products the files on this page are compatible with." http://www.hexachord.net/cakewalk-cal/

Comment: thanks, the ability to record scripts is always a good entry point to adapting/writing them, ill look into the range of products